# Add text to corner of HTML table cell without interfering with cell contents

Tags: html, css

How can I add text at the top right corner of a table cell without interfering with the existing text content of the cell?

For example, I have a simple HTML table:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Abc</td>
  <td>Defg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hijkl</td>
  <td>Mno</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How can I add a short (one or two word) "label" to the top right corner of a cell such that the table looks like this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pseudo elements to add to the td

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

td.one::after {
  content: 'stuff here';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}

td.two::after {
  content: 'different stuff';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}


td::after {
  content: attr(data-tag);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>jaflkasdjf ajl;fjasd;lfja ;lfj a;ljf a jaljfdlajflaj</td>
    <td class="one">lajflajd ajlfkkjd flaj jla jkfa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="two">jaflkasdjf ajl;fjas</td>
    <td>lajflajd ajlfkkjd flaj jla jkfa</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>jaflkasdjf ajl;fjasd;lfja ;lfj a;ljf a jaljfdlajflaj</td>
    <td data-tag="this is text">lajflajd ajlfkkjd flaj jla jkfa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-tag="this is different">jaflkasdjf ajl;fjas</td>
    <td>lajflajd ajlfkkjd flaj jla jkfa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cLpshjk9/9/

Edit: update for comment.

Comment: the code is pretty small so why not creating a working snippet here? I don't see the need of jsfiddle

Comment: @TemaniAfif Added. I still include fiddles so the OP can play with it, rather than just run it.

Comment: But this will cause the *same* content to be added to *every* cell.  Right?

Comment: @synaptik yes, you will need to use classes to target specific cells. I edited the snippet.

Comment: @synaptik no need different classes, use data attribute https://jsfiddle.net/cLpshjk9/10/

Comment: @TemaniAfif good call on the data-attributes. I added that to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put a div inside the td, make it position relative. Add that label as span/div or whatever element, make it absolute with `top: 0, right: 0`

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Abc</td>
  <td>Defg<span> some label </span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hijkl</td>
  <td>Defg<span> some label </span></td>
</tr>
</table>

table {
  border:1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  position: relative; 
}

td span {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: gray;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ykor79mL/

Answer (score -2):

```
Use Following code :
```

`<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Table Data come here
        <div class="topright">Next Code</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css">
td {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

td .topright { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
</style>`

Comment: You should explain briefly your code and it's purpose.

Comment: What you are not able to get in this. its very simple.